# Validations for custom alert view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

I've added a custom view to an alert view.

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyView"];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Submit", nil];                                                                                                           
[alertView setValue: myViewController.view  forKey:@"accessoryView"];              
[alertView show];
```

There are a few textfields in `myViewController.view`. The alert view has two buttons "Submit" and "Cancel".

[image]

On tapping "Submit" button I need to validate the inputs in textfields. If input is not valid, I don't want to dismiss the alert. E.g. If email is not valid, I'll show another alert saying "Email is not valid". How shall I acheive this? I tried following things so far:

1) Writing validation logic in following method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

But the alert view dismisses after executing this method.

2) Subclassing UIAlertView. I tried to override the following method in subclassed UIAlertView:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```

This method is not invoked though I tap any of the buttons on alert view. Apple says,

```
The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.
```

I've spent much time today to resolve this problem, but no luck..!! Please help me.

Comment: Just create your own AlertView, because alertview is only to be used as is. You are using private methods for setting your custom view which may get you app rejected.

Comment: I think you can use something out of the delegate method.

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

Comment: Or you could put the "Submit" UIButton in the myViewController that looks similar to the cancel button with same dimensions, at the bottom of the myViewController.view and keep just one button in the alertView to cancel the alert.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to replace `UIAlertView` with something else. [TTAlertView](https://github.com/twotoasters/TTAlertView) and [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView) are both under active development and should allow you the flexibility to subclass and/or skin the view any way you need.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that you should consider creating your own alert view replacement.  That said here are a few options that use a `UIAlertView`.

1) Don't use the native `UIAlertView` buttons (cancel / submit).  Instead, incorporate your own buttons into your accessory view, and configure the `UIAlertView` itself without any buttons.  Now you have full control.  But your buttons will not look exactly like the native alert view buttons because you can't position them in the right place.

2) Instead of validating your user's input once the submit button is tapped, you can attempt to disable the submit button until the form as a whole validates.  That is, keep the submit button disabled until it passes validation.  The problem with this is there is very limited capability in the `UIAlertView` for disabling / enabling the submit button.  If you use the `UIAlertView`'s native `UIAlertViewPlainTextInputStyle` you'll note that you can enable/disable the submit button via the delegate callback `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:`.

I was able to build off of this behavior and enable/disable the submit button based on my own UITextField in the accessory view (while using `UIAlertViewDefaultStyle`).  There's a very good argument to be made NOT to use this technique because it is very borderline using undocumented mechanisms. (Okay, it's pretty much over the line...).  But here's my solution, for completeness:

Note, `TSAlertViewFormController` is the `UIViewController` who's view is used as the `accessoryView` of the `UIAlertView`.  You need to ensure the view controller itself (not just its view) stays alive for the same duration as the `UIAlertView` that is containing it.  Also, you need to set the weak `alertView` property on it!

```
@interface TSAlertViewFormController () <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation TSAlertViewFormController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField*    _textField;
}

- (BOOL) alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView;
{
    // validate all your fields here!

    return [_textField.text isEqualToString: @"abc"];
}

- (void) setAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertViewHost
{
    [self view];

    _alertView = alertViewHost;

    // sniff out the selector used to handle textfield editing events
    // this could (should!) be considered "undocumented" behavior
    // (one major issue is we assume the target is the UIAlertView itself!)
    UIAlertView* avtemp = [UIAlertView new];
    avtemp.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UIControl* avtempTextField = [avtemp textFieldAtIndex: 0];

    NSArray* actions = [avtempTextField actionsForTarget: avtemp forControlEvent: UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    if ( actions.count > 0 )
    {
        SEL action = NSSelectorFromString( actions.lastObject );

        // route our text field editing-changed events to the host alert view
        // do this for each textfield!
        [_textField addTarget: self.alertView action: action forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    }
    else
    {
        // need to fail gracefully here...
    }
}

@end
```

Here's how it's used:

```
@implementation TSViewController
{
    TSAlertViewFormController* _avc;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _avc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"avc"];
    _avc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300);

    UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: nil
                                                 message: nil
                                                delegate: _avc
                                       cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                                       otherButtonTitles: @"Submit", nil];

    _avc.alertView = av;

    [av setValue: _avc.view forKey: @"accessoryView"];
    [av show];
}
```